# C++: meaning of std::ostringstream& var

Tags: c++

I want to implement a function with a parameter that will receive a `string` result:

```
bool function (entry parameter, std::ostringstream & var)
```

I'm not sure about what it is, pointer ?

Should I do something special about it or just: `var << result` ?

The return value is `boolean` but we will need `var` after

Answer (score 1):

& means it is a reference, not a pointer.  See Andrew's comment link.  You do not need to delete var, if that is what you mean by "something special."  Given the method signature you provided, the code:

```
var << result;
```

should work just fine, assuming "result" is something sane.  If you need more information, you may need to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it meande a reference, I understand now :) Big thanks